# Payara 6 failed to launch

Tags: payara

I am trying to launch payara 6, with `sudo ./asadmin start-domain`  but i get the following error: Waiting for domain1 to start ....Error starting domain domain1.
The server exited prematurely with exit code 1.
Before it died, it produced the following output:

```
Waiting for domain1 to start ....Error starting domain domain1.
The server exited prematurely with exit code 1.
Before it died, it produced the following output:

Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 9009
Launching Payara Server on Felix platform
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime@4378dda5 in service registry.
Completed shutdown of GlassFish runtime
We are in non-embedded mode, so fish.payara.server.core.nucleus.glassfish [317] has nothing to do.
ago. 02, 2023 12:14:42 A. M. com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner createBundleProvisioner
INFORMACIÓN: Create bundle provisioner class = class com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.
ago. 02, 2023 12:14:42 A. M. com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.LogFacade log
ADVERTENCIA: Failed to install file:/usr/local/payara/payara6/glassfish/modules/libpam4j-repackaged.jar.
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to cache bundle: file:/usr/local/payara/payara6/glassfish/modules/libpam4j-repackaged.jar
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:3258)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleContextImpl.java:147)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.install(BundleProvisioner.java:448)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.installBundles(BundleProvisioner.java:208)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:142)
    at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime._bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:114)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(GlassFishMain.java:136)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMain.java:121)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:54)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: Invalid CEN header (invalid zip64 extra data field size)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.zerror(ZipFile.java:1728)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.checkExtraFields(ZipFile.java:1261)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.checkAndAddEntry(ZipFile.java:1212)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1667)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:1445)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1407)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:716)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:250)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:193)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.openZipFile(SecureAction.java:802)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.WeakZipFileFactory$WeakZipFile.<init>(WeakZipFileFactory.java:169)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.WeakZipFileFactory$WeakZipFile.<init>(WeakZipFileFactory.java:151)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.WeakZipFileFactory.create(WeakZipFileFactory.java:78)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.JarRevision.<init>(JarRevision.java:83)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleArchive.createRevisionFromLocation(BundleArchive.java:804)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleArchive.reviseInternal(BundleArchive.java:491)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleArchive.<init>(BundleArchive.java:155)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleCache.create(BundleCache.java:457)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:3254)
    ... 13 more

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMain.java:121)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:54)
Caused by: A MultiException has 2 exceptions.  They are:
1. com.sun.enterprise.module.ResolveError: Failed to start OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [fish.payara.server.internal.batch.glassfish-batch-connector [267]], State = [NEW]
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load descriptor SystemDescriptor(
    implementation=org.glassfish.batch.spi.impl.BatchRuntimeConfigurationInjector
    name=batch-runtime-configuration
    contracts={org.glassfish.batch.spi.impl.BatchRuntimeConfigurationInjector,org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigInjector}
    scope=jakarta.inject.Singleton
    qualifiers={org.jvnet.hk2.config.InjectionTarget}
    descriptorType=CLASS
    descriptorVisibility=NORMAL
    metadata=@table-suffix={optional,default\:,datatype\:java.lang.String,leaf},@data-source-lookup-name={optional,datatype\:java.lang.String,leaf},@table-prefix={optional,default\:,datatype\:java.lang.String,leaf},@schema-name={optional,default\:APP,datatype\:java.lang.String,leaf},@executor-service-lookup-name={optional,default\:concurrent/__defaultManagedExecutorService,datatype\:java.lang.String,leaf},target={org.glassfish.batch.spi.impl.BatchRuntimeConfiguration},Bundle-SymbolicName={fish.payara.server.internal.batch.glassfish-batch-connector},Bundle-Version={6.2023.7}
    rank=0
    loader=OsgiPopulatorPostProcessor.HK2Loader(OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [fish.payara.server.internal.batch.glassfish-batch-connector [267]], State = [NEW],1699265405)
    proxiable=null
    proxyForSameScope=null
    analysisName=null
    id=126
    locatorId=0
    identityHashCode=237484673
    reified=false)

    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.loadClass(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2262)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:433)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:452)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.DomDocument$InjectionTargetFilter.matches(DomDocument.java:184)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getDescriptors(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:342)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getDescriptors(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:384)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getBestDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:392)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.DomDocument.buildModel(DomDocument.java:135)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigModel.parseValue(ConfigModel.java:959)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigModel.<init>(ConfigModel.java:875)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.DomDocument.buildModel(DomDocument.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.DomDocument.getModelByElementName(DomDocument.java:162)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigParser.handleElement(ConfigParser.java:172)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigParser.parse(ConfigParser.java:108)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigParser.parse(ConfigParser.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.config.support.DomainXml.parseDomainXml(DomainXml.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.config.support.DomainXml.run(DomainXml.java:121)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigurationPopulator.populateConfig(ConfigurationPopulator.java:58)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.bootstrap.HK2Populator.populateConfig(HK2Populator.java:83)
    at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.populateConfig(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:190)
    at com.sun.enterprise.module.bootstrap.Main.createServiceLocator(Main.java:249)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.HK2Main.createServiceLocator(HK2Main.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime.newGlassFish(EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishRuntimeDecorator.newGlassFish(GlassFishRuntimeDecorator.java:68)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntime.newGlassFish(OSGiGlassFishRuntime.java:91)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(GlassFishMain.java:137)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: com.sun.enterprise.module.ResolveError: Failed to start OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [fish.payara.server.internal.batch.glassfish-batch-connector [267]], State = [NEW]
    at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.OSGiModuleImpl.start(OSGiModuleImpl.java:193)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.OsgiPopulatorPostProcessor$1.loadClass(OsgiPopulatorPostProcessor.java:54)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.loadClass(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2254)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve fish.payara.server.internal.batch.glassfish-batch-connector [267](R 267.0): missing requirement [fish.payara.server.internal.batch.glassfish-batch-connector [267](R 267.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.ibm.jbatch.spi) [caused by: Unable to resolve fish.payara.server.internal.batch.payara-jbatch [241](R 241.0): missing requirement [fish.payara.server.internal.batch.payara-jbatch [241](R 241.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.glassfish.weld) [caused by: Unable to resolve fish.payara.server.internal.web.weld-integration [294](R 294.0): missing requirement [fish.payara.server.internal.web.weld-integration [294](R 294.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.glassfish.web.deployment.descriptor)(version>=6.2023.0)(!(version>=7.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve fish.payara.server.core.web.glue [135](R 135.0): missing requirement [fish.payara.server.core.web.glue [135](R 135.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.enterprise.security.ee)(version>=6.2023.0)(!(version>=7.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve fish.payara.server.core.security.ee [337](R 337.0): missing requirement [fish.payara.server.core.security.ee [337](R 337.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.jvnet.libpam)(version>=5.12.0)(!(version>=6.0.0)))]]]] Unresolved requirements: [[fish.payara.server.internal.batch.glassfish-batch-connector [267](R 267.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.ibm.jbatch.spi)]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4398)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2308)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:1006)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.OSGiModuleImpl.startBundle(OSGiModuleImpl.java:224)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.OSGiModuleImpl.start(OSGiModuleImpl.java:185)
    ... 33 more

Command start-domain failed.
```

i am using java 17 on a debian system

I tried using root `su -`, and still the output was the same, I tried using `sudo ./asadmin start-domain --debug domain1` and the output was the same, change the install location from /usr/local/payara to / opt/payara, and continuous output sineod the same and tried to launch it from intellij and in the intellij console it gave the same output

Answer (score 0):

Hello I had a similar issue to start payara server from netbeans 18 and I Fixed it changing the payara jdk platform. I was using JdK 17 Temurin and I changed it by jdk17 by oracle and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I caught the same error with the latest Payara Server Community Edition 6.2023.7 and Oracle JDK 17.0.8 (LTS) on openSUSE Tumbleweed.
The recipe [here](https://forum.payara.fish/t/error-starting-payara-community-server-6-2023-7-from-netbeans/667) has helped me. I added to the domain's config file `{PAYARA_INSTALL_DIR}/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml` the following property before starting the domain:

```
...
<java-config classpath-suffix="" ...>
    ...
    <jvm-options>-Djdk.util.zip.disableZip64ExtraFieldValidation=true</jvm-options>
</java-config>
...
```

Then I started the domain with the standard command `{PAYARA_INSTALL_DIR}/bin/asadmin start-domain` and all works fine.